# Enigma assigment plugboard possiblitys

Tags: combinations

I'm currently working on a assigment, where I have to find out the number of possible combinations when coupled 5 wires of the plugboard and Generalize the calculation to reflect the number of possible combinations of "n" wires.

I did find out how many combinations the 5 wires make which is

(26*25)/2*(24*23)/2*(22*21)/2*(20*19)/2*(18*17)/2*1/5! = 5.019.589.575

Now I need to found out how I make a formela for "n" wires. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that your numerator is $\frac {26!}{16!}$  Can you replace the $16$ with an expression that depends on $n$? Think about the $n=1$ and $n=2$ cases.  Then the $5!$ becomes ... and how many factors of $2$ are in the denominator?

Comment: I'm not a 100% sure I understand what you mean. What do you mean that the numerator is 26!/16!.

Comment: You are multiplying all the numbers from $26$ down to $17$.  One way to express that is to multiply all the numbers from $26$ down to $1$ which is $26!$ and divide by all the numbers from $16$ down to $1$, which is $16!$.  This shows up in many combinatorial problems.

Comment: So it would be something like (26!/16!)/32*1/5!=5019589575 right? Now I need to replace the 16! with an expression that depends on n, but how do I do that?

Comment: Well 16! can be (26-10) or (26-2*5) - 5 is wires which have 2 endes and therefor we * med 2.
(26!/(26-2*5)!)/32*1/5!

Comment: and is there a way to move the /32 or do something with this?

Comment: You divide by $2$ once per wire because you can choose the ends in either order.  That would become a factor $2^n$ in the denominator.  You divided by $5!$ because you can change the order of the wires that many ways.  What would that be for general $n$?

Comment: It would be $26!/(26-2n)!*1/2^n$, but it doesn't give the right answer. EDIT it would be $26!/((26-2*n)!*2^n )*1/n!$ right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct